# Will I ever spoil my iPhone by placing it on top of my laptop?

Tags: iphone, hardware

Does anyone know if I will ever spoil my iPhone by placing it on top of my laptop?

I mean I don't know about these electronic/magnetic stuff and I want to know if there may be any problem putting them close together (especially when my laptop is running and heated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your iPhone will not spoil if placed on your laptop. Unless it is so hot that your [iPhone warns you about its temperature](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201678).

Concerning the electronic/magnetic *stuff*, your laptop will not give out that much amount of *stuff* to spoil the iPhone, unless your laptop is a microwave.

Answer (score 1):

Though it won't likely damage your laptop or phone, it's a general rule of thumb not to place two electronics on top of each other.
Will you spoil your phone at that moment? Very low chances. Will you *ever* spoil your phone by doing it? Very high chances.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop still includes a HDD, the risk might be higher for the laptop than the phone, especially if your iPhone is set to vibrate.